# как вывести имя владельца, права доступа и дату создания файла?

Tags: linux, bash

нужно выводить отдельно имя владельца, права доступа и дату создания.

команда `ls -l` выводит все и сразу. нужно, чтобы скрипт выводил их по отдельности (каждое - с новой строки).

подскажите команды.

Comment: То есть надо просто разбить по полям и вывести через `\n`? Всё это - `awk`.

Comment: проще наверное так обьяснить (кусок скрипта):
`echo "владелец: $(...)"
echo "права доступа: $(...)"
echo "дата создания: $(...)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

например, так:

```
$ stat --printf="%U\n%A\n%y\n" файл
user
-rw-r--r--
2014-11-21 00:34:37.899050859 +0300
```

подробности о значении опций смотрите в [`man stat`](https://opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=stat&category=1&russian=0).

---

одно уточнение: дата создания файла (по крайней мере в файловых системах семейства *ext**), увы, не фиксируется.

Answer (score 2):

Или как-то так:

```
ls -l файл | \
awk -F' ' '{printf( "%s\n%s\n%s %s, %s\n", $3, $1, $7, $6, $8);}'
```